# Image Upload in Progress 4gl

Tags: image-uploading, openedge, progress-4gl

How to upload multiple images and save it locally or in server in progress 4gl and rename each images? tried to search google with keywords "upload images in progress 4gl / openedge" but no results.

Comment: Platform? Webspeed? Winform? Custom windows controls?

Comment: Windows.. Progress App Builder ver 9.1E

Answer (score 1):

Good day:

i found a few codes in the internet and after a few tweeks this is my code:

```
OS-CREATE-DIR VALUE(todr_name).
stat = OS-ERROR.
IF stat NE 0 THEN
  MESSAGE "Directory not created. System Error #" stat.

ic = 0.

INPUT FROM OS-DIR (frdr_name).

REPEAT:
    IMPORT cFileShort cFileLong cType. 

    /*MESSAGE /*cFileShort*/ /*cFileLong*/ cType VIEW-AS ALERT-BOX INFO.*/

    /* File or Directory ? */
    IF cType MATCHES "*F*" THEN DO:
        ic = ic + 1.
        /*MESSAGE "ShortFileName" cFileShort SKIP
                "LongFileName" cFileLong VIEW-AS ALERT-BOX INFO.*/

        MESSAGE STRING(ic) + ".jpg" VIEW-AS ALERT-BOX INFO.

        OS-COPY VALUE (cFileLong) VALUE (SUBSTITUTE (todr_name, cFileShort )).
        OS-RENAME VALUE(todr_name + "\" + cFileShort) VALUE(todr_name + "\" + STRING(ic) + ".jpg").

        /*IF OS-ERROR = 0 THEN 
            OS-DELETE VALUE (cFileLong).*/
    END.

END.
```

Comment: If this works for you and you're satisfied with what you found please mark your answer as accepted. This way other people will know what the question has been answered.